# Unable to modify eclipse.ini file in snap

Tags: 18.04, eclipse

I have installed eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04 via Snap. And in the snap folder, I can see eclipse, where I want to add few lines in eclipse.ini file, but I'm getting "E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override) " msg , even I'm not able to change file permission.

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 586 Apr  5 20:25 /snap/eclipse/12/eclipse.ini

Comment: Editing `/snap/eclipse/*/eclipse.ini` is impossible, but [I've found a way to use a different `eclipse.ini` when launching Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051926/how-to-make-eclipse-installed-via-snap-use-a-differerent-configuration-when-star/1051927#1051927).