# How to make Eclipse installed via snap use a differerent configuration when started from global menu

Tags: eclipse, snap, ubuntu-mate

[Files from software installed via snap are read-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043619/unable-to-modify-eclipse-ini-file-in-snap?noredirect=1&lq=1). To configure Eclipse, however, we need to change its `eclipse.ini` file. How to do it so, when pressing the Super key and clicking on Eclipse's logo, it uses the new configuration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many possible solutions but the my favorite/simplest one is to use [Menulibre](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre/):

1. Copy `/snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini` to somewhere you can edit it. Let us say, copy it to `/etc/eclipse.ini`.
2. Edit the arguments you want to update<sup>[1]</sup> and save the file.
3. Open Menulibre<sup>[2]</sup>
4. Search for "Eclipse."
5. Click in the Eclipse icon.
6. In the "Command" input, add the `--launcher.ini` option after the binary path. In our example, we would replace

   ```
    /snap/bin/eclipse %U
   ```

   with

   ```
    /snap/bin/eclipse  --launcher.ini /etc/eclipse.ini %U
   ```
7. Click in Menulibre's "Save" button. I have only tested it on Unity and MATE, though, not sure it is going to work with GNOME 3.

So far, it is working to me.

---

## Notes

<sup>[1]</sup> I, for example, changed

```
    -Xms
    256m
    -Xmx
    1024m
```

to

```
    -Xms
    1024m
    -Xmx
    4096m
```

<sup>[2]</sup> You may have to install it. A way to do it is to use APT:

```
$ sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Comment: Very helpful answer for ubuntu users

Comment: Apparently, you can simply copy `/snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini` to `${HOME}/snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini`, where you can edit it, and it will **automatically** get picked up by the snap. Note, that both `current/` subdirs are links the actual version of the snap (e.g. `66/` in my case). You will have to repeat this procedure every time the snap is upgraded to a new version.